# Delete all issues in MongoDB collestion

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to write a function that deletes all items in a MongoDB collection. I thought this might do what I want:

```
const removeAll = (req, res) => {
  Issue.deleteMany({}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      })
    }
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Issues successfully removed!"
    })
  })
```

It returns this though:

```
404 Not Found
Cannot DELETE /api/issues/
```

How can I deletew all issues?

Comment: This error isn't related to MongoDB. This is related to your routing tool such as the express routing utilities.

Comment: D'oh. I had `router.route('/api/issues') .post(authCtrl.requireSignin, issueCtrl.create)`. Should have been `router.route('/api/issues') .delte(authCtrl.requireSignin, issueCtrl.create)`. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error wasn't related to MongoDB. It was related to my routing express routing utilities where I had `router.route('/api/issues') .post(authCtrl.requireSignin, issueCtrl.create)`. Should have been `router.route('/api/issues') .delte(authCtrl.requireSignin, issueCtrl.create)`.